# Typing for dynamically generated class methods

Tags: python

I wrote a tiny, compact, minimal logger for Python apps that are little more than slightly large scripts.  It has colors (which are very important), and allows you to define a custom level (a custom `log.<level_name>` and color) by just adding a new tuple to the list of levels passed to the `Logger` constructor.

However, since the methods are defined on the resulting class instance dynamically, Pylint in VS Code can't find the methods when I invoke them.

Is there any way, e.g. with type hints, to tell Pylint/all static-analysis tools about these methods or at least have them not worry about them?

Here's the class's source:

```py
class Logger:
    def __init__(self, levels):
        max_level_len = max(len(l) for l, _ in levels)
        for level, color in levels:
            l = level.rjust(max_level_len)
            func = eval(f"lambda msg: print('\x1b[1m{color}{l}:{color} ' + msg + '\x1b[0m')")
            setattr(self, level, func)
```

Usage:

```py
log = Logger(
    [
        ("info", "\x1b[94m"),
        ("exec", "\x1b[96m"),
        ("warning", "\x1b[93m"),
        ("error", "\x1b[91m"),
        ("critical", "\x1b[91m"),
        ("fatal", "\x1b[91m"),
        ("success", "\x1b[92m"),
        ("debug", "\x1b[95m"),
    ]
)

log.info("Test")
log.critical("Test")
```

Comment: Static analysis tools *can't really work with dynamically generated types*, no?

Comment: As an aside, your use of `eval` here seems totally unnecessary...

Comment: Hmmmm you're really right.....

Comment: Yeah it seems unnecessary to me too, but I must've written it for a reason.  I'll check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "find the methods" - you mean the `log.info` methods?

Thats probably because your `Logger` class isn't inheriting from anything, so doesn't have those methods.

Probably a better approach than what you are trying is to define a formatter. Something like this-

```
colors = {
    'default': 'aaaa',
    logging.DEBUG: 'bbbb',
}

class ColoredFormatter(Formatter):
  def __init__():
    super().__init__(fmt="%(levelname)s <whatever else you want>")

  def formatMessage(record):
    record.msg = f"{colors[record.level]}record.msg{colors['default']}"
    super().formatMessage(record)


handler = StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(ColoredFormatter)
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[handler])
```

Comment: Ah, nifty trick! @DeepSpace true, but I like this better.  If it works, I'll use it instead.  Thank you @PaulBecotte!